# mandrill web-hooks open event "list of opens"

Tags: mandrill

We are using mandrill, and we have webhooks configured to track **open** events.
But I am a bit confused about the JSON format what mandrill provides.

In of the formats, for open event, we have a key called **"opens"**

```
"opens": [
        {
          "ts": 1420010190,
          "ip": "0.0.0.0",
          "location": null,
          "ua": "Linux/Linux/Gmail image proxy/Gmail image proxy"
        },
        {
          "ts": 1420020155,
          "ip": "0.0.0.0",
          "location": null,
          "ua": "Linux/Linux/Gmail image proxy/Gmail image proxy"
        },

 ],
```

- Are these objects unique ?
- will they be duplicates? if so, do mandrill adds all the open list for every event we receive?
  From the docs what i could understand is mandrill sends a webhook for every open, if it is, what are these list of opens in every event. which one would i consider.

It will be really helpfull, if someone explain the format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to record the individual opens, just use the data at the top level of the webhook event (`ts`, `event`, `location`, `ip`, for example). Everything under the `msg` key is data about the message that Mandrill knows when the webhook is created (so it's in addition to information about the individual open that triggered the webhook event). So the `msg.opens` key will be a list of **all** opens Mandrill knows about for the message at that time.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I forgot to mention in the question, yes i want to record all the opens and clicks. So i guess its the same thing for clicks too, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. The `msg.clicks` will contain all clicks for the message, not just the one triggering the event.